# CashPaymentFlow always generates anonymous change output

Tags: corda

The CashPaymentFlow has a parameter `anonymous` to say whether the recipient should be replaced by a confidential identity. In my case, I don't want the confidential identity, so I set it to false.
This works fine for the recipient output (Contains the well known party) but not for the change output to the sender (Contains an anonymous Party).

This happens even if the original sender input is *not anonymous*

Im on Corda Release 4 on a ubuntu azure VM.

```
fun sendPayment(amount: Amount<Currency>, recipient: Party): AbstractCashFlow.Result? {
        val anonymous = false

        val handle = proxy.startTrackedFlow(::CashPaymentFlow, amount, recipient, anonymous)
        return handle.returnValue.get()
}
```

Assume we are sending from A to B and have one unspent output with owner A and value 1000 EUR. Now call `sendPayment` with amount 800 EUR and recipient B.

I would expect two outputs:

- 800 EUR, owner B
- 200 EUR, owner A

Instead I get

- 800 EUR, owner B
- 200 EUR, **Anonymous(SDFOMWEORHEWLRKHWLEKR...)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Historically, change from cash spends in Corda have been returned using confidential identities. This is the default functionality when generating a spend with either confidential or well-known identities and can't be overridden through CashPaymentFlow.

The [Tokens SDK](https://github.com/corda/token-sdk) will be replacing Cash (and the rest of the finance module) in due course through which you'll be able to make anonymous change keys optional.